# android save image from camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera

Hi I am trying to use this code to save image,

[google camera preview](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html)

but I am having problem. where should i add code to save image?

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesmultimedia/278-using-camera-api-in-android